Git Client For A Bare Repository
Do you know a github-like bare repository hosting tool of git?
In my company, an shared file server is available but web server is not available.Then I found git bare repository. It seems to be able to be used on the shared file server.
I found git clients like git gui, git kraken, tortoise git and so on.But those clients don't have issue management and pull requests like github.Is there such a client tool? I would like to use bare repository on the shared file server like github repository.

GitLab has a free self-hosted option, maybe that's what you are after?

Issues and pull requests are not a part of Git itself - those are added on by other developers, and they're centralized. If you want those, then you'll need to use a service like GitHub or GitLab, or a self-hosted Git server.
